# xPath - Microsoft Sql - how to get a specific attribute from all child nodes

Tags: sql-server, xpath

I have a XML like this:

```
    <Table Name="Table">
        <TableHeader>
          <TableCol Name="Date"/>
          <TableCol Name="Number"/>
          <TableCol Name="Reason"/>
          <TableCol Name="Time"/> 
        </TableHeader>
 </Table>
```

and I want to get a result like this:

```
HeaderName
-------------------
Date
Number
Reason
Time
```

my xPath query is this:

```
SELECT  *   FROM    OPENXML (@xmlHandle, @docDescriptionTable)
wITH (  HeaderName  varchar(255) '/Table/TableHeader//TableCol/@Name'       );
```

and I get just this Result:

```
HeaderName
---------
Date
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using [**`nodes() Method`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188282.aspx)

```
declare @xml xml  = '  <Table Name="Table">
        <TableHeader>
          <TableCol Name="Date"/>
          <TableCol Name="Number"/>
          <TableCol Name="Reason"/>
          <TableCol Name="Time"/> 
        </TableHeader>
 </Table>'

SELECT
   col.value('./@Name','varchar(50)')
FROM
   @xml.nodes('/Table/TableHeader/TableCol') AS t(col)
```

**Result :**

```
HeaderName
----------
Date
Number
Reason
Time
```